# for loop isn't working inside a class element

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

My codes should have shown 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 . But it is showing only 10. what is the error??But it works when I write (document.write(x);) . codes are given below

```
    for(x=0;x<=10;x++){

        document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML=(x+"</br>");

    }
```

Comment: You're overriding the content of the element on each round of the loop. Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: because you're updating same element again and again

Comment: It's because in each iteration you overwrite the `innerHTML` value instead of adding the value with `+=`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to append the inner html and not override it. Otherwise only the last iteration is present.

```js
for(x=0;x<=10;x++){
document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML += (x+"</br>");
}
```

```html
<p class="for"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missed appending data to the HTML. Instead of replacing the `innerHTML`, you can keep adding to it inside the loop like -

```
document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML+=(x+"</br>");
```

Run the code snippet below to check.

```js
for(x=0;x<=10;x++){

        document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML+=(x+"</br>");

    }
```

```html
<div class="for"></div>
```

Comment: `+=` is not an append operator, it replaces the original string.

Comment: Huh? @Teemu what do you mean? Even the official docs propse to use this syntax over the concat function? "It is strongly recommended that the assignment operators (+, +=) are used instead of the concat() method." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

Comment: @Aaron Strings are immutable, you can't append any content to a string. `+=` is just a shortcut to `var = var + str`.

Comment: Very picky but you are probably right, good point. misunderstood you @Teemu

Comment: @Aaron Not picky at all. It does the job in this case, but ex. if you had an attached event listener on an element inside the element you change with `innerHTML`, the listener would be gone, because a new element(s) is/are created every time.

Comment: Well I just used his example and based my answer on that. I would have solved it quite different but good point! Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Here's what your loop is essentially doing:

```
 //sets .for's content to  0<br>
 document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML=(0+"</br>");

 //sets .for's content to  1<br>, erasing what was there before
 document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML=(1+"</br>");

 //sets .for's content to  2<br>, erasing what was there before
 document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML=(2+"</br>");

 ...

 //sets .for's content to  9<br>, erasing what was there before
 document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML=(9+"</br>");
```

Each cycle in the loop is setting the content to something new, overriding what was already there.

If instead, you want to add to what is already there then you should do something like:

```
for(x=0;x<=10;x++){
    document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML = document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML + ( x+"</br>"  );
}
```

**BONUS:**

Javascript offers a simplified way to 'adding to what is already there' with the `+=` syntax. E.g:

```
a = a + 1;
```

could be written as:

```
a += 1;
```

In the same way:

```
a = a + 5;
```

... could be written as:

```
a += 5;
```

And in the same way:

```
document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML = document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML + ( x+"</br>"  );
```

... could be written as:

```
document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML += (x + "</br>");
```

So you could actually use that and simplify your code to:

```
for ( x=0; x<=10; x++ ) {
    document.querySelector(".for").innerHTML += (x + "</br>");
}
```

And while I'm at it, a little performance boost that could have an impact if you were doing a bigger loop:

```
const element = document.querySelector(".for");

for ( let x = 0; x <= 10; x++ ) {
    element.innerHTML += (x + "</br>");
}
```

Instead of querying the document for the same element each and every cycle of the loop, you query it once and store a reference to it before the loop, and refer to it in the loop.